# FusionCharts column_2D chart

Tags: fusioncharts

How to set the y-axis interval, or 'tick mark?' with a min value of 0 and max value of 9, I'm seeing tick marks every '2', like 0,2,4,6,8,10.  I don't want that.. I want y-axis lines every .25

Funny, in fusion charts I can set the background color of the yaxis labels, put a dashed border around the background, even control the space size between the dashes.. but I can't set something important like the tick mark interval

Comment: Refer this topic  : https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/div-lines-and-grids

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts supports 'numDivLines' that allows you to specify the number of divisions on the y-axis. The number of lines required for the chart can be calculated using min and max values. Set 'adjustDiv' to 0. This will force fusioncharts to use the user-defined 'numDivLines'.

JS-Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spranali/yvmq0ab1/44/

```
adjustDiv: 0,
numDivLines: 35,
yAxisMinValue: 0,
yAxisMaxValue: 9,
```

The height of the chart has to be scaled to occupy the specified y-axis intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to specify the minimum and maximum values for the y-axis, as well as the number of divisional lines -

Set the adjustDiv attribute to 0 to disable the automatic adjustment of divisional lines.

Specify the custom lower limit y-axis value using the yAxisMinValue attribute.

Specify the custom upper limit y-axis value using the yAxisMaxValue attribute.

Set the number of divisional lines using the numDivLines attribute.

```
"adjustDiv": "0",
"yAxisMaxvalue": "9",
"yAxisMinValue": "0",
"numDivLines": "3.5"
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/marc1749/2/)